# Error in hibernate config xml : Failed:org.hibernate.MappingException: Error reading resource: com/

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I am a beginner practicing hibernate ORM, I need help in resolving below Exception:
Thank you

Entitiy:

```
package com.ds.supercar.model.usermodel;
```

public class Address {

```
private String emailid;
private String mobile;
private String street;
private String city;
private String state;
private String country;
private String pin;

//GETTERS AND SETTERS
public Address() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public Address(String emailid, String mobile, String street, String city, String state, String country,
        String pin) {
    super();
    this.emailid = emailid;
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this.street = street;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.country = country;
    this.pin = pin;
}






public String getEmailid() {
    return emailid;
}
public void setEmailid(String emailid) {
    this.emailid = emailid;
}
public String getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}
public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}
public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public String getPin() {
    return pin;
}
public void setPin(String pin) {
    this.pin = pin;
}
```

}

hbm.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.ds.supercar.model.usermodel.Address" table="supercaraddress" schema="supercar">
        <id column="email"/>
        <property name="mobile"/>
        <property name="street"/>
        <property name="city"/>
        <property name="state"/>
        <property name="country"/>
        <property name="pin"/>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate cfg xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:SYSTEM</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl_auto">create</property>
```

org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle11gDialect
            true

Exception:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
```

log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Initial SessionFactory creation Failed:org.hibernate.MappingException: Error reading resource: com/ds/supercar/resources/mappings/usermodel/address.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Test.main(Test.java:19)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Error reading resource: com/ds/supercar/resources/mappings/usermodel/address.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1313)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1285)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1267)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1234)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1162)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1148)
    at Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: must specify an identifier type: com.ds.supercar.model.usermodel.Address
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindSimpleId(HbmBinder.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues(HbmBinder.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootClass(HbmBinder.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:360)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:446)
    ... 7 more

Please help me in resolving this problem:

Comment: Here is the remaining config XML file:

<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle11gDialect</property>
     <property name="show_sql">true</property>
     <mapping resource="com/ds/supercar/resources/mappings/usermodel/users.hbm.xml"/>

   <mapping resource="com/ds/supercar/resources/mappings/usermodel/address.hbm.xml"/>
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Comment: Well, two things: 1. set data type in hbm file type="string", that's fine. 2. If you have an application-context, write the reference to your hbm file to be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just are missing the `name` in your ID in the the mapping file.

From mapping XML:`<id name="emailId" column="email"/>`